# False positive "SharedPreferences.edit() without a corresponding commit() or apply() call" lint warning

Tags: android, kotlin, lint, android-studio-bumblebee

I got a lint warning on EVERY (already existing) sharedPreferences.edit() call after updating Android Studio to **Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2** from **4.2.1**

What's interesting, is that when I use it like this, I get the warning:

```
sharedPreferences.edit()
.putBoolean("example", true)
.apply()
```

But when I save it in a variable like this, I get no warning:

```
val sharedPrefEdit = sharedPreferences.edit()
.putBoolean("example", true)
.apply()
```

Any ideas why it's happening?
Any ideas how to resolve/prevent the warning without saving this operation in a variable unnecessarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a lint bug to me.

There is a handy [`edit` extension function](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/package-summary#(android.content.SharedPreferences).edit(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) that lets you make your updates in a lambda and it automatically applies the change. More concise, and it will avoid this lint warning:

```
sharedPreferences.edit {
    putBoolean("example", true)
}
```

You will need the `androidx.core:core-ktx` library in your dependencies if you don't already have it.